# OpenGLES - How to render two windows(surfaces) in the same thread efficiently?

Tags: android, opengl-es

When rendering two different surfaces in the same thread, I need to call `eglMakeCurrent` every time to unbind the current surface to the thread and to bind the other surface to the current thread before rendering a certain surface , while the operation of unbinding a surface to a thread consumes too much time!

SourceCode:

```
int DisplayPicture(...)
{   
    if (!eglMakeCurrent(m_glesDisplay ,m_glesSurface, m_glesSurface, m_glesContext))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    glUseProgram(programObject);

    glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 );
    glUniform1i(m_nUniformLocation[0],0);
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, nWidth, nHeight, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pData );

    ....

    // Update attribute values.
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, squareVertices);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_TEXCOORD, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, texCoords);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_TEXCOORD);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    eglSwapBuffers(m_glesDisplay, m_glesSurface);
    glUseProgram(0);
    return 0;
}
```

ps:
1. When using texture in OpenGLES, `eglMakeCurrent(display, NULL, NULL, NULL)` will cost a long time, why?
2. In some devices, `eglMakeCurrent` will return `EGL_BAD_ALLOC` while normal in other devices, why?